# Wordpress category/post color menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Can you tell me how you can make posts wordpress categories and with different colors?
I want to be the only menu in different colors as well as the category the items!
An example:
check out this site here that you like the color settings are changed as we post categories.

Comment: Did you try reading the [Wordpress documentation and tutorials](https://codex.wordpress.org/Blog_Design_and_Layout)?

Comment: @Dragos I read but do not understand, for this I am here to ask for help

Comment: sounds like what you need is to hire someone who does understand.

Comment: @vico Do not understand? Well I have explained above that I want to do with the color menu as in the example above! I want to do my page color as you see above as an example.

Comment: no what I am saying is you should just get a theme or hire someone who at least have some knowledge of wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of it depends on how your theme is set up, but here's a general overview:

### 1. Ensure that you are using the [body_class()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function

Check you theme's `header.php` and ensure the `body` tag looks something like:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This will automatically add a bunch of classes to your body tag, including classes depending on which category archive page you are viewing.

### 2. Use a filter to add category classes to single posts

Insert the following function into your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_body_class_add_categories( $classes ) {

    // Only proceed if we're on a single post page
    if ( !is_single() )
    return $classes;

    // Get the categories that are assigned to this post
    $post_categories = get_the_category();

    // Loop over each category in the $categories array
    foreach( $post_categories as $current_category ) {

        // Add the current category's slug to the $body_classes array
        $classes[] = 'category-' . $current_category->slug;

    }

    // Finally, return the $body_classes array
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_add_categories' );
```

This will also add the category classes to single posts.

### 3. Add classes for pages

The `body_class()` function can also be filtered to add classes for page slugs. Add the following to `functions.php`:

```
function my_body_class_add_page_slug( $classes ) {

    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }

    return $classes;

   }
   add_filter( 'body_class', 'my_body_class_add_page_slug' );
```

This will add the class `page-title` to the body.

### 4. Style as you please

This will vary according to your theme's markup, but it will be **along the lines** of:

```
.td-header-main-menu {
    background: blue; // The fallback colour for all pages
}

.category-showbiz .td-header-main-menu {
    background: red;
}

.category-sport .td-header-main-menu {
    background: yellow;
}

.category-shendetsi .td-header-main-menu,
.page-shendetsi .td-header-main-menu {
    background: green;
}
```

### Conclusion

That should give you the general idea; we can't give you more specific instructions without seeing the website itself or know which theme you're using.

Comment: This is my page so we've created categories not simply category page!
Web:  http://kosovatimes.com/

We changed colors but not within articles categor:
http://kosovatimes.com/lajme/ivan-xholev-mohon-se-eshte-thirrur-nga-prokuroria-deshmite-do-ti-paraqese-ne-keshillin-gjyqesor/

Comment: @Vlora I've updated the answer above to reflect your site's CSS. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand your last comment. I can see you've got it working for the 'shendeti' category.

Comment: Yes honored it operates in a category and items now have the opportunity to modify the code above to function even on site without categories?

Example: kosovatimes.com/category/shendetsi - its work
Example: kosovatimes.com/shendetsi - this is page does not work!

Comment: I've updated above to also add classes for page titles, so you can target your 'shendetsi' page as well.